# Lookup row with extra condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

With AMPscript I want to extract the `Start_date__c` from the row with the `Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c = True`. How can i achieve that? I tried a lot with LookupRows but every time it shows all three rows. Find my code below.

This is the DE with 3 rows:

```
Candidate__c         Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c     Start_date__c
003w000001P3Zc5AAF   False                            25-04-2017
003w000001P3Zc5AAF   True                             01-02-2017
003w000001P3Zc5AAF   False                            12-12-2016
```

This is the code i used

```
%%[

VAR @contact_DE, @contactID, @rowset_Startdate, @rowscount_Startdate, @row, @DEColumn1

SET @contact_DE = "Placement__c_Salesforce"
SET @contactID = [_subscriberkey]

SET @rowset_Startdate = LookupRows(@contact_DE,"Candidate__c",@contactID,"Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c","True")
SET @rowscount_Startdate = RowCount(@rowset_Startdate)

IF @rowscount_Startdate > 0 THEN

 FOR @i = 1 TO @rowscount_Startdate DO

 SET @row = Row(@rowset_Startdate, @i)
 SET @DEColumn1 = Field(@row, "Start_Date__c")

  ]%%


DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%% 

%%[ 
next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c`?

Comment: Hi Adam, the datatype is boolean.

Comment: I'd output the other fields from `Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c` in your loop and also change your lookup criteria to `"1"` instead of `"True"`.

Comment: Hi Adam, the code is not working at all. Can you post the correct code for me please?

Comment: Hi Adam, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd also output the value of `contactID` to ensure the you're getting the value for `_subscriberKey` that you should be.

Then I'd remove the `Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c` from your lookup and output it in your loop so you know the values that are getting returned.  If that looks good, then you can move it back to being part of the lookup.

```
%%[

var @Placement__c_DE, @contactID, @Placement__c_rows, @rowCount, @row

set @Placement__c_DE = "Placement__c_Salesforce"
set @contactID = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

output(concat("<br>contactID: ", @contactID))

set @Placement__c_rows = LookupRows(@Placement__c_DE, "Candidate__c", @contactID)
set @rowCount = RowCount(@Placement__c_rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

 for @i = 1 TO @rowCount do

     var @Start_Date__c
     var @Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c

     SET @row = row(@Placement__c_rows, @i)
     SET @Start_Date__c = Field(@row, "Start_Date__c")
     SET @Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c = Field(@row, "Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c")

     output(concat("<br>Start_Date__c: ", @Start_Date__c))
     output(concat("<br>Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c: ", @Clean_Order_Stage_Reached__c))

 next @i

else

     output(concat("<br>no ", @Placement__c_DE, " rows found"))

endif 

]%%
```